# Magento 2: Remove shipping address from customer account view order

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, sales

I need to override this in my custom theme -

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml

I remove or commented in core files directly, this block line -

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" as="info" name="sales.order.info" after="sales.order.view"/>
```

then it is working fine but when I override this XML in my custom theme then it is not working.

```
/app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not to copy all the XML file content in your `sales_order_view.xml` file. Just add the below line to remove the block from the page.

```
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.info" remove="1" />
```

After the changes, run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your **sales_order_view.xml** file in your custom theme and you only want to remove customer address data there then you can update this file in your custom theme like..

> app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this may work for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Way..

> app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Note: Please don't forget to clear cache after change in  xml files**

Comment: Could you please help me on this question.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Answer (score 1):

Add this line into the extended theme file of **sales_order_view.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.info" remove="true" />
```

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
    </body>
 </page>
```

Reason why it is not working when you removed the line from extended file. In your case multiple files with same name as **sales_order_view.xml** in theme and core so it all merge as single file and work.

Hope this helps.